# Does the "body" of Romans 8:10 describe the same "the body" of Romans 6:6 & Colossians 2:11?

Tags: sin, death, resurrection, circumcision, spiritual-birth

**Is the striking body language of Romans 6:6...**

> 6 We know that our old self was crucified with him in order that **the body of sin** might be brought to nothing, so that we would no longer be enslaved to sin.

**And Colossians 2:11...**

> 11 In him also you were circumcised with a circumcision made without hands, by putting off **the body of the flesh**, by the circumcision of Christ,

**...both explained/described in Romans 8:10?**

> 10 But if Christ is in you, although **the body is dead because of sin,** the Spirit is life because of righteousness.

**Is the *bringing to nothing of the body of sin* and *the putting off the body of the flesh* two ways of describing the state of Christians who undergo a type of spiritual divorce with their bodies, the upshot of which is described in Romans 8:10?**

Is the spiritual divorce christians have with our bodies such that we are made alive/united with God through a type of spiritual rebirth while our bodies are left dead/separated from God, because of sin, the current status being that we must wait until the physical resurrection for our spiritual reunification - that is for our bodies to be made alive through the Holy Spirit as we in our spirit have already been made alive through the Holy Spirit?

**Romans 8:11**

> 11 If the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, he who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through his Spirit who dwells in you.

Comment: The mortal bodies wil be resurrected because the Spirit dwells in us and we had put down the flesh to nothing. Not because it is still separated from God due to sin.

Comment: Yes, three slightly different ways of referring to the same thing.

Comment: Yes - all referring to same process of turning one's back on the old way of life for a new life in Christ.

Comment: @Dottard what do you think about the idea of our bodies being dead because of sin. Do you think that is merely a reference to the old way of life or is it a present reality we endure even while we've been spiritually made alive.

Comment: @Michael16, based on your response I thought I should make things more clear. Does that help?

Comment: It is a physical metaphor to teach a spiritual truth.  Interpreting a physical metaphor as literally true ends up in metaphysics and spiritism.

Comment: This looks like a theological synthesis question. Do you think you'd be able to edit it to more clearly focus on the exegesis of one passage?

Comment: Hi @curiousdannii, does the last edit better accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: The body of Romans 6:6 and Colossians 2:11 is put to death. The body of Romans 8:11 is given life. Might this suggest that they're different (i.e., the former represents Christians' past lives without Christ, while the latter is our literal bodies that will be raised)?

Answer (score 3):

The crucifixion and death of the "body of sin" or "body of flesh" has nothing to do whatsoever with the physical human body, which participates in regeneration through Holy Spirit together with its human created spirit/soul.

The "body of sin" or "body of flesh", or simply "flesh" indicates the sinful drives and inclinations, the general sinfulness of the entirety of human essence, both soul and body, which all humanity has since the fall of Adam and Eve. That's why Paul calls it in singular "sin" (Romans 5:12), indicating the general sinful condition of fallen nature of all humanity, rather than particular sins that are just its versatile and accidental expressions.

Comment: +1 I think you've done a great job differing with at least an aspect of my position while accurately representing the essence of it. I have a very different view of a type of "original sin" and hope to properly explore the topic with someone who actually believes the traditional version someday.

Comment: Ok, I do have a question. What do you think it means that presently our "body is dead because of sin" in Ro8:10. I ask because it seems like almost a direct reference to the "body of sin" discussed in 6:6. Do you think the dead body in 8:10 is the same thing as the mortal body in 8:11?

Comment: @Austin Thanks for your feedback and upvote, and the question: this is a difficult passage, for Paul seems to say that even those who live in Spirit have their bodies mortal because of sin; however in the immediate sequel he says that body will also be redeemed and deigned resurrection and immortality. This means necessarily that life in Spirit influences and transfigures not only soul but also body already in this life. It is an ontological necessity and unavoidability.

Comment: Thank you for your response it is something to think about. Concerning this statement, "This means necessarily that life in Spirit influences and *transfigures* not only soul but also *body already in this life,*" it seems to me to be precluded by Romans 8:11 itself that seems to locate the transformative activity of Spirit on the body into the future, instead of the present, at the resurrection implying the Spirit can presently be active in the body without transforming it, at least as far as I can understand it. Nevertheless, it is quite an interesting position worth pondering. Thanks again.

Comment: @Austin Oh, no! Do not hold such a gnostic, separatory idea! Just think: when I torture my body and soul through sin of alcoholism, then when I overcome alcoholism through Grace of Lord, I relieve and transfigure not only my soul, but certainly my body also! Impossible otherwise, ontologically impossible: you cannot get rich without making your family also rich, for your family is a necessary part of your enrichment.

Comment: Ok. I think I see. Is it your understanding that the body is still dead because of sin, and is in need of a complete re-creation found exclusively in the resurrection, but it still can be physically better off in its dead state with the improved life a person living in the Spirit would lead?  Also, if I understand your previous statements correctly do you see saying "the body is dead" is exactly the same as saying "the body is mortal"?

Comment: @Austin Body is mortal, but even the mortal body starts to participate in immortality already in this life. Mortality must not be equated with sinfulness. Lord's body died, but it was totally exempt from sin. The same with saints: their bodies die, but their bodies already in this life overcome death, for death of body is not ceasing of biological processes, but that body is led by sin. If body is not led by sin but by Grace, then it shares in victory over death. Thousands of saitns' bodies aren't decayed. Visit Milan, see for example St. Amborse's body, it decays not from 4th century onwards.

Comment: Levan Gigineishvili, thank you. I don't think I've heard that perspective before. That does help me to better understand your position.

Answer (score 1):

Op, stated:

"Is the spiritual divorce christians have with our bodies such that we are made alive/united with God through a type of spiritual rebirth while our bodies are left dead/separated from God, because of sin, the current status."

Even though sin is in our bodies it has been annulled, made powerless by Jesus condemning sin in the flesh.
If one lives under the law of course it will become very much alive.  The power of sin is the law.

The Scriptures OP quoted are great truths that we walk by faith in.

Since God has cleansed us He sees fit to have his Spirit dwells in our bodies at this time.
Our bodies are not divorced from Him.

> Or do you not know that your body is a temple of the Holy Spirit within you, whom you have from God? You are not your own, for  you were bought with a price. So glorify God in your body. 1 Corinthians 6:20

> The body is not meant for sexual immorality, but for the Lord, and the Lord for the body. And God raised the Lord and will also raise us up by his power. Do you not know that your bodies are members of Christ?  1 Corinthians 6:14-15

As Romans six states, Our old humanity was crucified, with Christ for us. (Adam as head of old creation) Even though we did not die we still may reckon His death as ours, fully finishing our connection with sin, and His Resurrection as ours also.  Now we live in His presence unspoiled by anything.

Colossians 2:11  stated the same thing.  We are now walking in the new humanity since Christ displaced the old Adam where sin and death were passed to all.  It was His Accomplishment through His death, burial and resurrection.
It was because of Christ's work, that we are no longer in the flesh.  We are no longer Identified with sins flesh.

Romans 8:10 is sandwiched between a couple other important versus.

> You however, are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if in fact the Spirit of God dwells in you. Anyone who does not have the Spirit of Christ does not belong to him. But if Christ is in you, although the body is dead because of sin, the Spirit is life because of righteousness. If the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, he who raised Christ Jesus  from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through his Spirit who dwells in you.

> SO then, brothers, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live according to the flesh.

Having that word  "so then"
or "therefore" means  to live according to what was written before it.  That means now in the flesh.

> The life I live in the body, I live by faith in the Son of God, who loved me and gave Himself up for me.  Galatians 2:20

We know that our bodies will be made incorruptible at a later time and the  conflict between  flesh and spirit will be gone.

Comment: +1 You have presented a potent challenge to my position with your use of 1 Corinthians 6. I have in my mind a solution that is not yet efficiently expressed which I may instead explore with another question. Thanks!

Comment: Sherrie, thanks again for your thoughtful response. I do have some questions for the purpose of clarification. Considering this statement, "Even though sin is in our bodies it has been annulled, made powerless by Jesus condemning sin in the flesh," how do you understand in Rom 8:10 that, presently, "the body is dead because of sin," even while we are alive spiritually? In what sense is our body currently dead? Does your statement mean to imply that sin is powerless over our own bodies? Does that mean our bodies are not dead because of sin? Thanks for any further clarity you can provide.

Comment: Austin, our bodies still have sin living inside our members  and therefore considered dead in that respect. Romans 5:12, Ro. 7:5,7:17,18,20,23,24 are a few verses that confirm why the body is in a sense  dead. The flesh  is not able to be subject to God's law.  The flesh is after the things of the flesh and leads to death. 
Wretched man that I am. Who will set me free from the body of this death?  Those that are Christ's now have  a spiritual force  that live inside our bodies as well and gives us power over our dead bodies.

Comment: "He is able vivify these death-doomed bodies, So that they respond to the dictates of the spirit." Concordant Commentary.  Does that help clarify anything?  Thanks for your questions as well +1

Comment: Thank you. That helps me understand your position.